# Good source of worked examples for Testing Infinite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

I'm looking for a source/s with a large number of worked examples in Testing Infinite Series using the following methods -

Divergence Test

Comparison Test and P Test

Ratio Test

Alternating Series Test

Power Series Test

Thanks.

Comment: The books in the Schaum's Outline series always have lots of worked examples. I don't know if there's one just for infinite series, but there's sure to be a chapter on series in the one for Calculus.

Comment: It's not a lot (about 15 series), but I have some examples worked out in the .pdf file titled "HW2notes.pdf" posted in this [22 December 2008 math-teach post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6544585) at Math Forum. I wrote these for a class I taught in 1998 to give students some model examples of how to concisely but informatively give justifications for their answers. (I asked for justifications, and not just answers, on their graded assignments and tests.)

Comment: I just noticed you asked for **series** examples, not **sequence** examples. O-K, use my previous handout for sequences, and use the file titled "series-converg+.pdf" that I posted in this [5 March 2010 math-teach post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7002409) at Math Forum for similarly worked example involving series.

Comment: Thanks! Do you by any chance know of any other good sources?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to search the internet for test solutions, such as [this google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=comparison+ratio+converges+diverges+series+solutions) and the corresponding search you get by replacing "solutions" with "examples".